# ipconfig.exe is crashing when run from the windows (7) command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-7, command-line-interface, ipconfig

I am trying to use ipconfig, but everytime I enter the command in the windows command prompt, I get the crash dialog saying, "The IP configuration utility has stopped working", with the reason saying "APPCRASH". Is there anyway I can remedy this issue without a reimage of the OS?

Comment: If you didn't mess with the executable, I would just reimage for peace of mind.

Comment: capture a dmp with Procdump (http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-9-ProcDump), open it in Windbg (part of the Windows SDK), fix the symbols (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503/en-us), now open the generated dmp with Windbg and run **!analyze -v**. Post the output here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you suspect that you have malware?  Are other command line utilities working? Did you recently install something that may have modified the required libraries?  Try grabbing ipconfig.exe from a known working machine and replacing yours with that copy.  If that fixes it, and nothing else is funky, I'd move on, otherwise you may want to confirm it's not something malicious.